# Slick Slider is not loading in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slick.js

Hey guys I have this HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>

 </head>

<body>

    <div class="slider">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

   <script src="main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

and this JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  prompt("Prompt 1");

  $('.slider').slick({

  });

  prompt("Prompt 2");

});
```

When I test this in browser (Chrome and Edge) the Slick plugin does not seem to be loading because the second *prompt* never shows up and the content inside *.slider* is one element below the other

However when I copy and paste both files in [plunker](http://plnkr.co) every thing appears perfectly.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check browser console  for any errors ?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah I just checked. it says ***Failed to load resource: cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css*** and  ***Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
slick.min.js***

Comment: Yes, from there you can get some clue of what is the issue.. All the best !!

Comment: thanks! you know why could be failing to load those files?

Comment: For me the given code is working. I can slide 1,2,3 numbers left and right.

Comment: it is working when I test it on www.plnkr.co but it is not when I open the file with the browser :( so weird!

Comment: This error means that file was not found. Either path is wrong or file is not present where you want it to be. Try to access it by entering source address in your browser to check if it really is there. Browse the directories on server to ensure the path is correct. You may even copy and paste the relative path to be certain it is alright.

Comment: Put your jquery code in your HEAD area with script tag.

Comment: i figured it out... I'll post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I was not including **https:** in my *link* tag and in one of the three *script*. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) was able to load the files but the browser could not do it without the **https:**

Solution:

instead of

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>`

add **https:**

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>`

same for the second *script* tag

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is the right url
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel-latest@1.9.0/slick/slick.min.js